# How to get the return value of INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN?

Tags: nsis

I'm try to get if the back bottom is clicked and avoid displaying the error message when one of input is not filled in.

Rigth now the $R9 variable is not filed is as I expect it.

```
Function SetCustom

  ;SectionGetFlags ${SEC04} $R0
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC05} $R5
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC06} $R6
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC07} $R7
  IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntOp $R5 $R5 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntOp $R6 $R6 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntOp $R7 $R7 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  IntCmp $R5 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  IntCmp $R6 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  IntCmp $R7 ${SF_SELECTED} show

  Abort

  show:
    Input:
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Customization" "Please input the Info1 and Info2 of the Customization user."
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "File.ini"
    !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "File.ini" "Field 2" "State"
    !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R2 "File.ini" "Field 3" "State"
    ;!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_SHOW_RETURN
    !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN $R9

    MessageBox MB_OK "$R9"
    ${If} "$R9" == "back"
        Abort
     ${Else}    
        StrCmp $R1 "" 0 +3
        MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK "Please enter a Info1."
        Goto Input

        StrCmp $R2 "" 0 +3
        MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK "Please enter a Info2"
        Goto Input
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you to `Pop`:

> If you need the return value, use the INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN or INSTALLOPTIONS_SHOW_RETURN macro. The return value will be added to the stack, so you can use the Pop command to get it.

```
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN "File.ini"
Pop $5
${If} $5 == "back"
  ...
${EndIf}
```

Comment: How does the variable $5 id decided?

Comment: You can `Pop` into any variable.

Comment: To reply to my question. The $5 is actually a non use variable in the function. In my current code to stay compliant to the pattern $R6 will work.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading there's one post from *pengyou* that can be found here:

https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-182393.html

The post ask for changing the function used to call the display of the page.

I changed all my call to be using the *MUI* version of it and I used *MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN* instead of *MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY*.

Also I change the order of the calls to the loading of the ini file is done prior to the configuration.

```
Function SetCustom      
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC01} $R0
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC02} $R4
  SectionGetFlags ${SEC03} $R5
  IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntOp $R4 $R4 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntOp $R5 $R5 & ${SF_SELECTED}
  IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  IntCmp $R4 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  IntCmp $R5 ${SF_SELECTED} show
  
  Abort
    
    show:
    InputMySQL:
    
    StrCpy $UserAborted "0"
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY_RETURN "file.ini"
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "MySQL customization" "Please input the username and password of the MySQL user."
    
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "file.ini" "Field 2" "State"
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R2 "file.ini" "Field 3" "State"
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R3 "file.ini" "Field 4" "State"
    
    Pop $R6
    
    MessageBox MB_OK "$R6" ;This will pop a message box comment it out for debugging
        

        ${If} $R6 <> "back"
            ${If} $R6 <> "cancel"
                ;Do validation code here
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```